# Android NDK include problems

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am currently reading the book "Beginning Android C++ Game Development" and after I import the source code, the headers do not work properly. It says that they are "unresolved inclusions" and cannot access them. Here is the source code for the top part:

```
#include <jni.h>

#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>

#include <android/sensor.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <android_native_app_glue.h>
```

If I manually key in the location, I can access the include files (I would have to type in the full address for each header file in the above code); and I have gone to properties, Paths and Symbols, and included them (they were automatically included). Here is a copy of my Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := hellodroid
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv2
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Never Mind, I got it to work. I would suggest that instead of importing the source code to create the original project; create your own project and the settings using the book's steps. Then just cut and paste the main.cpp or hellodroid.cpp files into the project. Do not import the whole project or else the code probably will show errors.